# Very late munin email alert

Tags: email, munin

I configured email alerts in Munin. It can send out the email correctly. But the problem is that even I removed one variable that will be monitored, munin will keep sending out email alerts on that variable. The munin email alert system shows very long delay.

How can I solve this problem?

The configuration is simple.

```
contact.monitor.command mail -s "munin warning notification" myemail
contact.monitor.always_send warning critical
```

Comment: Do you mean that let's say the disk is full, after the disk utilization returns to eg. 50%, munin keeps sending the emails? If yes, is the graph updated in the meantime with the correct value? Which version of munin do you use on the monitored and on  the monitoring host?

Comment: Thanks Aron. I finally found that the problem happened because of the postfix server accumulated the email queue.